# How do you assign null value to optional parameters in VB.NET 1.1

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-1.1

I tried DbNull.Value but no luck. How do I assign a default value as null to a string parameter that is null in VB.NET?  Its litte strange to see that VB does not have anything like plain null as most of the other languages do. Also what is the difference between null and DbNull and Nothing. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Nothing` is what you use in VB for `null`, so VB has no `null`, and `DBNull` is to be used to pass `null` to database when, for example, you are constructing a call to stored procedure and one of its input parameters needs to be null.

Answer (score 2):

use `nothing` instead of `null`

Answer (score 2):

VB.Net's closest equivalent to `null` is `Nothing`.

Note that this isn't a direct analog to C#'s `null`, but rather a closer match for C#'s `default(T)`.  However, it should do what you need here.

Comment: Thanks Joel (and others too).